# Securing client/server traffic using self signed certifiates in kind of a "pairing" process

Tags: openssl

I have two machines, let's call them "Server" and "Gateway", communicating through SSL. A PKI cannot be established, communications outside a company private LAN is not permitted. Both machines can create self-signed SSL certificates (OpenSSL).

Communications is always initiated by the "Server".
The "Gateway" doesn't not need to distinguish different users, but it may give out data to the "server" it is paired with only.
Both "Server" and "Gateway" are set up manually at the same time and location by trained personnel and could therefore be "paired" using a "something" derived from a "shared secret", like a common password dreamed up by the integrator. The "common secret" should not be stored anywhere after the "pairing", if either machine needs to be rebuilt it is acceptable to repeat the whole "pairing" process.

Without PKI, is there any way to utilize (Open)SSL based on something *derived* from a "shared secret" which cannot be mimicked without knowing that "shared secret" AND beeing able to generate the "something" only if one has access to the "Server" and "Gateway" boxes?

Comment: First off, PKI does not require communication with any host other than the two hosts involved in the connection.  In your case, the 'server' is acting like a client (because it is initiating the connection), and the 'gateway' is acting as a server (because it accepts a connection).  It seems like TLS with a client certificate on your 'server' would solve your problem - i.e. securing the connection between the two hosts, with both hosts being able to mutually authenticate each other.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48802/how-to-validate-a-client-certificate for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. It showed me the way to "mutual SSL authentication", which looks what I was looking for. Unfortunately I cannot mark a comment as an answer, can I?

Comment: Glad this helped.  Good luck with your project!